# keep div's side by side inside absolute div of fixed width & height

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem while centering a div of fixed width & height and placing two divs side by side inside it. What i want to achieve, at later point of time, is the slide to left effect on the second div (on top of first div) based on some event. Below is what i tried:

HTML:

```
<div id="center">
    <div id="firstel"></div>
    <div id="secondel"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#center{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
#firstel{
    background-color:red;
}
#secondel{
    background-color:blue;
}

#firstel,#secondel{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j41uxdLa/1/)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: will you elaborate ?

Comment: your outer container and divs inside were of same width, how it will show side by side.. change any of those values.. might be like this you can so http://jsfiddle.net/j41uxdLa/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
#center{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%; //change this
    overflow:hidden;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/j41uxdLa/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`#center` and `#firstel,#secondel` ID's were of same width(200px), If you need to show side by side eitherof the ids values have to be changed

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j41uxdLa/4/)**

```
#firstel,#secondel{    
    width:50%; /* changed value in % or you can use 100px too as per your need */
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: That i tried to change parent's div width...Any other workaround or it is not possible to achieve ?

Comment: can you show your expected output as image to get idea?

Answer (score 0):

if u want the two divs side by side 
change the widths of the divs 
change the divs width that shoild be less than the parent div width

```
#firstel,#secondel{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
```

}